# Forcing grub menu to external monitor connected to laptop via HDMI/VGA

Tags: boot, grub2, laptop, hdmi, external-monitor

Is there any way to force grub menu to show it's content in external monitor (for selecting the os to boot on win or ubuntu), I use my laptop more like a desktop with a monitor connected to it because of broken laptop fan socket. Either HDMI or VGA would work.

Comment: Can you set the `bios` of the laptop to display on an external monitor ? That should do it for `grub` too. This is the only real solution I found on Google, but not all laptops have this option.

Comment: Mine doesn't have that :( #hatelaptop

Comment: OK Might of got lucky with this, I assume, because of overheating you would be fine with not having the laptop display on when the desktop boots, right ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bad way to do this, for most, that may just be good for you.

On desktop, open this file as root

```
gksu gedit  /etc/default/grub
```

and find this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=...
```

and add a this to the end

```
video=LVDS-1:d
```

my whole line is

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

so I would add it here

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=LVDS-1:d"
```

Change `lvds-1` for you monitors name, if it is different, find it with

```
xrandr -q
```

Save and exit, and run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will disable the Laptop display for both `grub` and the desktop and force it to the external display, even if you remove the `HDMI` cable, the laptop screen will not work. You can remove the change to change it back to using the laptop screen.

I can't test this as I don't have a laptop, but I took it from [an question at `arch`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=150413), where the issue was no laptop display after forcing `grub` to an external monitor.

I don't recommend this for most users who want there laptop to still be portable.

Comment: will give it a try and come back asap.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work: the menu is not displayed on the external monitor. The external monitor is only activated after Linux has booted.

Comment: I just dealt with the same problem and the answer by @Mark Kirby helped a lot! For me it was essential to replace `LVDS-1` with the name of the built-in laptop screen provided by `xrandr -q`. I would additionally advise to run `sudo update-grub` after you made the changes and before you reboot.

Comment: @Mark could you precise what is the `d` in `LVDS-1:d`? By the way, if you have time, I asked a related question in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286892/start-grub-on-external-monitor-as-laptop-monitor-unresponsive-broken Thanks!!

Comment: @Matifou I am not 100% sure because this was a while ago and I can't find any documentation right now but I think d is for "disable" and using e would be "enable", so LVDS-1:d would disable the laptop display.

Comment: i tried with changing my monitor name as well. it just does not work. my main monitor is eDP:1.

Comment: this answer is WRONG, don't even try it. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT are used to build a command line for the linux kernel and can only take effect AFTER A KERNEL IS SELECTED FOR BOOT. it wont have any effect before a selection is made, and thus won't have any effect on where the menu is displayed.

Comment: :d is disable, :e is enable, and :D is enable in digital mode.

Comment: @Matifou https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/modedb.html

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of sounding overly simplistic, I learned, through a bit of experimentation, that hardware engineers are aware of the issue and have responded. On my old but trusty Toshiba Satellite S55 laptop (from 2013), the monitor at boot can be selected or left up to auto-select. In auto-select mode (the default), the computer will activate an external monitor if the lid is closed on the laptop. I just tried it and it works! Definitely worth a try, but check your hardware boot settings, YMMV.