# Grub menu to second monitor

Tags: boot, grub2, hdmi, external-monitor

On my dual-boot Acer laptop (win8.1 and 14.04) I mostly use the HDMI port and 24" monitor. Sometimes I need to boot to windows but can't see the grub menu as the laptop internal monitor is turned off.

This guy has the same issue.
[Force grub to use monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712111/forcing-grub-menu-to-external-monitor-connected-to-laptop-via-hdmi-vga)

So far I cannot find anything that works, good or bad practices not withstanding.

I checked the BIOS settings and nothing there for monitors.

Can anyone help out with this please?

Comment: Have you tried pressing Fn+F8 on your keyboard right after power on to see if it will change to the external monitor to see grub there?

Comment: @Terrance: Thanks, I think that may have done something but of course could not see it. The monitor just showed "No Signal" but after waiting a few minutes and no response, I did a three-key-reset and it booted to Ubuntu as normal. So it was probably a menu asking which monitor to use. DUH!!