# Power Off Resets Display Settings

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, shutdown

I have a dual monitor system and I want to keep the bigger one as the primary monitor; I can make it so from Displays, but every time I power off Ubuntu forgets that I even meddled with Display settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer on this other question [Connect an external monitor to laptop with broken screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067861) will work.

But as I said, I'm on Lubuntu, and I don't know what screen configuration and autostart packages / tools ship with Ubuntu. But I hope it provides as least a place to start working.