# Start grub on external monitor (as laptop monitor unresponsive/broken)

Tags: grub2, startup, external-monitor

How can I have grub start by default on an external monitor? My problem is that my laptop screen is broken/unresponsive, and I cannot see grub, as the external monitor is started only once grub has selected Ubuntu! I can hear the grub beep, count the 5 seconds timeout, but I never am able to access the grub menu?

Unfortunately, the method in this [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712111/forcing-grub-menu-to-external-monitor-connected-to-laptop-via-hdmi-vga) changing defaults in `/etc/default/grub` does not seem to work:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=LVDS-1:d"
```

and I replaced `LVDS-1:d` with `DP-1-2-2`, from:

```
$ xrandr -q
eDP-1-1 connected
DP-1-2 disconnected 
DP-1-2-2 connected
DP-1-2-3 connected primary
```

But this does not work, I don't see grub, and the monitor only starts once Ubuntu has been selected. I can think of 3 explanations:

1. I am not specifying the screen the right way? What is the `d` in `LVDS-1:d`?
2. I use actually encryption, not sure if that changes anything
3. Laptop is connected to a dock, which handles the dp ports

Any idea? Thanks!!

Thanks!